# Escribir en un jtextfield según una consulta sql y una fila seleccionada de un jtable

Tags: java, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi base de datos:

socios

```
Id                    Integer clave primaria auto increment
numero_socio          int
nombre                varchar
apellidos             varchar
nif                   varchar
fecha_nac             date
telefono              int
correo                varchar
direccion             varchar
fecha_alta            date
fecha_baja            date
```

asamblea

```
id                    clave primaria auto increment
acta                  mediumtext
tipo                  varchar
fecha                 date
convocante            varchar
```

junta_directiva

```
id clave              primaria auto increment
id_socio_presidente   int (relación con id de un socio)
id_socio_secretario   int (relación con id de un socio)
id_socio_vocal1       int (relación con id de un socio)
id_socio_vocal2       int (relación con id de un socio)
id_socio_vocal3       int (relación con id de un socio)
id_asamblea           int (relación con id de una asamblea)
periodo               varchar
```

Tengo un jtable donde muestro los registros de la tabla junta_directiva de la siguiente forma:

Nombre y apellidos de cada socio relacionado (presidente,secretario y los 3 vocales)
Fecha de la asamblea
Id de la junta directiva
Periodo de la junta directiva

Este es el código:

```
void cargar(String valor) {
    try {

        String[] titulos = {"Id", "Presidente", "Secretario", "Vocal 1", "Vocal 2", "Vocal 3", "Asamblea", "Periodo",};
        String[] registros = new String[8];
        model = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);


        String cons = "SELECT a.fecha AS FechaAsamblea,\n"
                + "p.nombre AS NombrePresidente,\n"
                + "p.apellidos  AS ApellidosPresidente,\n"
                + "       jd.id,\n"
                + "       periodo,\n"
                + "       s.nombre    AS NombreSecretario,\n"
                + "       s.apellidos  AS ApellidosSecretario,\n"
                + "       v1.nombre   AS NombreVocal1,\n"
                + "       v1.apellidos AS ApellidosVocal1,\n"
                + "       v2.nombre   AS NombreVocal2,\n"
                + "       v2.apellidos AS ApellidosVocal2,\n"
                + "       v3.nombre   AS NombreVocal3,\n"
                + "       v3.apellidos AS ApellidosVocal3\n"
                + "FROM junta_directiva jd\n"
                + "INNER JOIN socios   p  ON jd.id_socio_presidente = p.id\n"
                + "INNER JOIN socios   s  ON jd.id_socio_secretario = s.id\n"
                + "INNER JOIN socios   v1 ON jd.id_socio_vocal1 = v1.id\n"
                + "INNER JOIN socios   v2 ON jd.id_socio_vocal2 = v2.id\n"
                + "INNER JOIN socios   v3 ON jd.id_socio_vocal3 = v3.id\n"
                + "INNER JOIN asamblea a  ON jd.id_asamblea = a.id";

        Statement st = cn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(cons);


        //Introducimos los registros de la base de datos en la tabla
        while (rs.next()) {
            registros[0] = rs.getString("jd.id");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("NombrePresidente") + " " + rs.getString("ApellidosPresidente");
            registros[2] = rs.getString("NombreSecretario") + " " + rs.getString("ApellidosSecretario");
            registros[3] = rs.getString("NombreVocal1") + " " + rs.getString("ApellidosVocal1");
            registros[4] = rs.getString("NombreVocal2") + " " + rs.getString("ApellidosVocal2");
            registros[5] = rs.getString("NombreVocal3") + " " + rs.getString("ApellidosVocal3");
            registros[6] = rs.getString("FechaAsamblea");
            registros[7] = rs.getString("periodo");
            model.addRow(registros);
        }
        jTable1.setModel(model);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Bien, pues necesito mostrar en 5 textfield cada id de cada socio relacionado y en otro textfield el id relacionado de la asamblea. 
Me explico, según la fila que seleccione en la tabla, necesito que en el textfield1 se muestre el id del presidente de la fila seleccionada, en el textfield2 el id del secretario de la fila seleccionada y así con los demás socios y el id de la asamblea.
Agradecería una solución

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el diseño hace complejo las búsquedas, y lo hace muy rígido. Imagínate que de repente decidan que se requieren 4 Vocales o 2 Secretarios; tendrías que modificar demasiado código.  Peor aún, en la consulta que haces, así con "inner joins", si a un consejo le faltar un vocal o secretario, no te va arrojar ningún resultado. La consulta lo va brincar.

Yo haría estos cambios:

```
junta_directiva

    id clave              primaria auto increment
    id_asamblea           int (relación con id de una asamblea)
    periodo               varchar

participantes_junta_directiva

    id_clave_junta       int (relación con la junta directiva)
    id_parcitipante      int (relación con id de un socio)
    tipo_de_participante int (socio, vocal1, secretario, etc)
```

Entiendo que tu pregunta es otra, pero quizás este esquema simplificaría mucho las consultas a base de datos, y el llenado de las tablas.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia. Sé que es una consulta muy rígida e inamovible pero está hecho también para un modelo inmóvil dónde es imposible que haya una junta incompleta o que requiera más socios que esos 5.